# Our [compass] needs calibrating

Tags: discussion, tag-disambiguation

There used to be only 2 compass tags:  [compass-sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compass-sass) and [compass-geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compass-geolocation).  Questions involving Compass, the Sass framework, were often mistagged with compass-geolocation because it was always suggested first (due to alphabetization) and users don't always double check what they're selecting.  This past January, compass was added as a synonym of compass-sass.

However, there appear to be a number of questions with the compass tag that have nothing to do with Sass or Compass, [most of them appear to be related to phones](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=votes&q=%5bcompass%5d%20-%5bcompass-sass%5d%20-%5bsass%5d%20-%5blibsass%5d%20-%5bcss%5d%20-%5bcss3%5d%20-%5bgem%5d%20-%5bgulp%5d%20-%5bruby%5d%20-%5bruby-on-rails%5d%20-%5bintellij-idea%5d%20-%5bgruntjs%5d%20is%3aquestion):

- [True heading and true course of an iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27417907/true-heading-and-true-course-of-an-iphone)
- [Compass: Rotate image towards a particular location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167325/compass-rotate-image-towards-a-particular-location)
- [Cordova compass API (navigator.compass.watchHeading) not working (error code 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642057/cordova-compass-api-navigator-compass-watchheading-not-working-error-code-3)
- [Android orientation: azimuth depends on pitch and roll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32445673/android-orientation-azimuth-depends-on-pitch-and-roll)

So the question becomes, what *should* these questions be retagged with?  Is compass-geolocation appropriate?  There's no wiki for it and the excerpt is fairly vague.

> Geolocation is the identification of the real-world geographic location of an object, such as a cell phone or an Internet-connected computer terminal. Geolocation may refer to the practice of assessing the location, or to the actual assessed location.

And finally, should the compass synonym be kept at all?

Number of questions for each tag:

- compass: 430
- compass-geolocation: 292
- compass-sass: 1806

Comment: IMO, the synonym of compass <=> compass-sass should be undone. A disambiguous tag for electronic compass modules should be applied to the 4 questions you've listed (compass-sensor perhaps?) and THAT should have the compass synonym. As for users not reading, I don't see any retag effort eliminating the problem.

Comment: Whichever topic has more questions should get the [tag:compass] synonymization.

Comment: There are 70 questions with [both compass and compass-sass](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcompass%5D+%5Bcompass-sass%5D+is%3Aquestion) that could have one tag removed with no loss of information. Plus 231 more that are tagged with [(ruby or sass) and compass](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcompass%5D+-%5Bcompass-sass%5D+%5Bsass%5D+or+%5Bruby%5D+is%3Aquestion), which could be  tagged compass-sass.

Comment: @Mogsdad Using Sass does not necessarily imply using Compass as well. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777215/what-is-compass-what-is-sass-how-do-they-differ

Comment: @TylerH No, but it is a good indicator as to which "compass" pile it should go into.

Comment: Have you tried waving it in a figure-8 pattern yet?

Comment: This is still an issue. I was asking a question about the compass sensor in my android device.  [tag:compass-geolocation] does not seem applicable because it has *nothing* to do with geolocation.  I guess I'm throwing in a vote for [tag:compass-sensor].