# Disambiguating the [GLM] tag: 'Generalized Linear Model' vs OpenGL vector math library

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

The [glm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glm) tag represents questions asking about Generalized Linear Models. However, it just so happens that there is a vector math library with the hopelessly uninspired name of OpenGL Mathematics, or in short: GLM. Its tag is [glm-math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glm-math).

The problem is that people asking questions involving GLM-math are, well, newer users. Which means that they're not likely to look up what a tag actually means. They're using GLM-the-math-library, so they'll just stick "GLM" there and call it a day. They'll probably even feel validated when they see that it's already an existing tag.

This is a real problem. See, there are over 650 questions tagged with [glm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glm). However, doing a [simple search of `[glm] [opengl]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glm+opengl), we find that there are over 150 such questions. Not only is this larger than the 126 questions correctly tagged with [glm-math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glm-math), it also means that nearly 1 in 4 questions tagged with [glm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glm) is probably tagged incorrectly. And that doesn't count questions that talk about the math library without being tagged with OpenGL [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33391365/autoconf-glm-headers).

What can be done to fix this problem? Or at least mitigate it?

Now, I am *not* suggesting that we change the name of the [glm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glm) tag. Generalized Linear Models existed long before that math library, so the name rightfully belongs to them.

But there's got to be something that can be done here. Even if someone goes through and cleans up the tag, it will still constantly accrue this sort of cruft. The [glm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glm) blurb already contains an admonishment to use [glm-math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glm-math), but clearly it's not working.

What can we do to prevent these kinds of mistakes?

Comment: "`What can we do to prevent these kinds of mistakes?`" --- make users read and think before writing. Should be easy. Right? ..... right??

Comment: Well, they might have existed far longer. Doesn't prevent them from getting expropriated though, like swift.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Well, we can try, but it still probably won't be very effective.

Comment: And don't forget the [GLM Wavefront OBJ loading library](http://devernay.free.fr/hacks/glm/).

Answer (score 5):

What about getting rid of the ambiguous `glm` tag and force the use of more explicit tags such as:

1. non-verbose

   - `glm-math`
   - `glm-opengl`
2. verbose

   - `generalized-linear-models`
   - `opengl-math`

Comment: Isn't option 1) the same amount of "drastic"? And if there isn't a general `glm` tag, then users already have to actively choose either, hopefully making them give a thought to what they want.

Comment: Edited my answer :)

Comment: The only problem I have with this is that it requires *swapping* a tag to mean the opposite of what it used to ([tag:glm-math]).

Comment: Someone will come along and propose the "glm" synonym and we'll be right back where we started (see: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307224/our-compass-needs-calibrating; used to have unambiguous tags that were regularly misapplied, but now we have an ambiguous synonym to go with them).

Comment: Isn't there a way for moderators to blacklist tag names? What if I was to tag `some-bad-word` for instance?

Comment: No, mods can only ask CMs and devs to do that.

Comment: @Mr_Pouet You have to have a ton of reputation to create a non-standard tag, like a `some-bad-word` tag, and then that post could be flagged, since the tag is inappropriate/irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

- `glm-math` is not a very disambiguating name, but we're stuck with it now.
- `glm-model` for Generalized Linear Model
- Leave the `glm` tag intact, with a disambiguation text saying:
  "Don't use this tag: use the following:"

  - `glm-math` for the OpenGL vector library
  - `glm-model` for Generalized Linear Model